# How to work with unsaved entities even though ID attribute is needed?

Tags: reactjs, postgresql, typescript

I'm creating a React application where my data has the following structure:

```
interface BookCase {
    id: number;
    bookShelves: BookShelf[];
}
interface BookShelf {
    id: number;
}
```

Every bookcase and every bookshelf has an id property. I use this for the `key` attribute and for locating a bookshelf inside the bookShelves array. The id is generated in the backend by the database (With a `BigSerial` in PostgreSQL) on save.

I now want to create a new bookcase inside my frontend *without* immediately saving it to the backend. First I want to work with it, perform some operations on it (e.g. place a book on the shelf), and afterwards send the whole batch of changes with the new entities to the backend where it will then be persisted in the database.

Of course I do not yet have an id, although I need one to work on the bookcases. Should I rewrite my application to also accept `null` for id (I would prefer not to)? Should I just randomly create an temporary id, possibly having duplicates with the ids already present in the database (or for example use a negative value like -1)? Then I would need to replace all the ids afterwards after it has been saved to the database.

With UUIDs I could generate it on the frontend, but I guess there also has to be a common pattern to work with just incrementing integers as the id.

Comment: Give them a `clientId` property?

Comment: Ok, I understand, but then I would need to keep this in mind almost everywhere in the code, right? For example, if I say that a book is placed on shelf 23, how do I know that this is the `clientId` or the normal `id`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not think there is a clear answer here.

Essentially you have a object-relational mapping and there are various ways to handle it. Entity Framework for example just uses the default for the data type. So if the entity does not exist yet the ID will be `0` and any persisted entities have values starting at `1` so there are no conflicts.

One way i usually handle saving is by returning the updated record from the request, so you just replace your old one with that and you have the correct ID value applied automatically.

Comment: Thanks. As there really does not seem to be a clear answer, I think in my case the best way (or at least an easy way) would be to increment into negative numbers. Then I can have multiple unsaved entities, do not have clashes with the existing entities and after bulk saving everything, I will incude an `oldId` in the response so that I can update the ids.

Comment: @Hellstorm: Sounds reasonable 